# Casting a list of lists to IGrouping?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, linq-to-objects

I have some code that creates a list of lists. The list is of this type:

```
 List<List<Device>> GroupedDeviceList = new List<List<Device>>();
```

But need to return the result in the following type:

```
 IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, Device>>
```

Is this possible via a cast etc or should I be using a different definition for my list of lists?

Comment: What would be the key of your groupings ? A property of the devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your intentions correctly, the answer is below:

```
    var result = GroupedDeviceList
        .SelectMany(lst => lst.GroupBy(device => (object)lst));
```

result is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, Device>>`, where object is a reference to your `List<Device>`.

Answer (score 1):

`IGrouping<T1,T2>` is usually created via a LINQ `GroupBy` query.

How are you populating `GroupedDeviceList`?  Are you doing this manually or converting it from the result of a `.GroupBy`?

You could perform the grouping again by doing something like this:

```
// IEnumerable<IGrouping<TWhatever, Device>>
var reGroupedList = 
    GroupedDeviceList
    .SelectMany( innerList => innerList.GroupBy( device => device.Whatever ) );
```

Comment: That would return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGrouping<TWhatever, Device>>>`

Comment: @Thomas Should have used `SelectMany` of course, answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the contents of each non-empty list should form a group...

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, Device>> query =
  from list in lists
  from device in list
  group device by (object)list;
```